# Laravel 5 - Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found

Tags: laravel, redirect, authentication, routes

I am trying to redirect the `Laravel` page to another other that home after login, but it redirects me to `home` every time. What I've done is: I changed the value of `protected $redirectTo =` from `home` to `protected $redirectTo = 'S1CheckUserTables';`.
I also defined my route in `web.php` as follows (I beleived that I shall use a named route):

```
Route::get('/S1CheckUserTables', ['as'=>'S1CheckUserTables', 'uses'=>'S1CheckUserTablesController@index']);
```

I also tried using the following syntax to fix the issue but it didn't work either:

```
Route::get('S1CheckUserTables', 'S1CheckUserTablesController@index')->name('S1CheckUserTables');
```

Would you please tell me what could solve my problem? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default redirect for laravel after login is to go to /home set in the LoginController:

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

and there is default middleware RedirectIfAuthenticated

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and in app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

So that is where you need to make changes in order to work your way...

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but it still redirects to `home`. Is there anything else in addition to to changing what you said that I should do to make it work? I am Using `make:auth`.

Comment: No. Only these two: middleware RedirectIfAuthenticated and LoginController

Comment: According to the page below I changed all three values but still have the same problem. Isn't there something wrong with my routing? Or shouldn't I refresh or reset the databese somehow or ...? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#included-authenticating

Comment: do you have any middleware that you have created?

Comment: No, anctualy I should have also changed the value in `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController` to make the redirection happen to where I wanted (after the registeration is successful). Thank you very verry much. I learned a lot.

Comment: No problem...glad i could help. I will update my answer